# What I can do to resolve "1 commit behind master"?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, branching-and-merging, git-merge-conflict

After pushing I've been seeing this message at remote repository:

> 1 commit behind master.
>
> This merge has conflicts that must be resolved before it can be committed.
>
> To manually merge these changes into TA20footerLast run the following commands:
>
> `git checkout 7c891f50c557`
>
> **Note**: This will create a detached head!
>
> `git merge remotes/origin/master`

Comment: If you want to see what that 1 new commit is on master, run `git log -1 -p origin/master`

Answer (score 142):

Before you begin, if you are uncomfortable with a command line, you can do all the following steps using **SourceTree**, **GitExtensions**, **GitHub Desktop**, or your favorite tool.

To solve the issue, you might have **two scenarios**:

---

#### 1. Fix only remote repository branch which is behind commit

Example: Both branches are on the remote side

ahead === Master branch

behind === Develop branch

**Solution:**

1. Clone the repository to the local workspace: this will give you the Master branch, which is ahead with commit

   ```
   git clone repositoryUrl
   ```
2. Create a branch with Develop name and checkout to that branch locally

   ```
   git checkout -b DevelopBranchName // this command creates and checkout the branch
   ```
3. Pull from the remote Develop branch. **Conflict** might occur. if so, fix the
   conflict and commit the changes.

   ```
    git pull origin DevelopBranchName
   ```
4. Merge the local Develop branch with the remote Develop branch

   ```
     git merge origin develop
   ```
5. Push the merged branch to the remote Develop branch

   ```
     git push origin develop
   ```

---

#### 2. Local Master branch is behind the remote Master branch

This means every locally created branch is behind.

Before preceding, you have to commit or stash all the changes you made on the branch behind commits.

**Solution:**

1. Checkout your local Master branch

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
2. Pull from remote Master branch

   ```
   git pull origin master
   ```

Now your local Master is in sync with the remote branch. As a result of the above command, other local branches branched from the previous local Master branch are not in sync. To fix that:

1. Checkout the branch that is behind your local Master branch

   ```
   git checkout BranchNameBehindCommit
   ```
2. Merge with the local Master branch

   ```
   git merge master  // Now your branch is in sync with the local Master branch
   ```

If **this branch** is on the remote repository, you have to push your changes.

```
    git push origin branchBehindCommit
```

Comment: At 1) -> 3) gives an error: Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Answer (score 81):

If your branch is behind by master then do:

```sh
git checkout master (you are switching your branch to master)
git pull 
git checkout yourBranch (switch back to your branch)
git merge master
```

After merging it, check if there is a conflict or not.
If there is NO CONFLICT then:

```
git push
```

If there is a conflict then fix your file(s), then:

```
git add yourFile(s)
git commit -m 'updating my branch'
git push
```

Comment: Generally, the developers don't have permission to push into master. In that case, this solution will be better:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59064413/8872674

Answer (score 55):

1. Clone your fork:

   - `git clone git@github.com:YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-FORKED-REPO.git`
2. Add remote from original repository in your forked repository:

   - `cd into/cloned/fork-repo`
   - `git remote add upstream git://github.com/ORIGINAL-DEV-USERNAME/REPO-YOU-FORKED-FROM.git`
   - `git fetch upstream`
3. Updating your fork from original repo to keep up with their changes:

   - `git pull upstream master`
   - `git push`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. Works like a charm.

Comment: works perfectly fine, very well explained!

Answer (score 27):

If the message is "n commits behind master."

You need to rebase your dev branch with master.
You got the above message because after checking out dev branch from master, the master branch got new commit and has moved ahead.
You need to get those new commits to your dev branch.

Steps:

```
git checkout master
git pull        #this will update your local master
git checkout yourDevBranch
git rebase master
```

## there can be some merge conflicts which you have to resolve.

Comment: Just wanted to add that rebasing should only be used with private branches: https://blog.axosoft.com/golden-rule-of-rebasing-in-git/

Comment: Rebase should be applied carefully since it rewrites the commits hash and can lead to some problems.

Comment: Already did this, Throws error

Answer (score 6):

Suppose currently you are in your branch `myBranch`
Do the following :-

```
git status
```

If all changes are committed

```
git pull origin master
```

If changes are not committed than

```
git add .

git commit -m"commit changes"

git pull origin master
```

Check if there are any conflicts then resolve and commit changes

```
git add .

git commit -m"resolved conflicts message"
```

And then push

```
git push origin myBranch
```

Answer (score 3):

1. git checkout master
2. git pull origin master
3. git checkout BranchNameBehindCommit (your branch)
4. git merge master
5. git push origin branchBehindCommit

Comment: "Everything up-to-date". I tried. I got this "Everything up-to-date". not worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

simple fix

1. clone repo to your system

   `git clone repositoryUrl`
2. Go to the branch that has commits behind the master branch

   `git checkout branch_name`
3. Rebase the branch to master

   `git rebase -i origin/master`
4. vi code editor will open, type :wq and click enter

   `:wq`
5. Finally push chages to the branch ,there won't be any commits behind now

   `git push -f`

Comment: this is most simple one.

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at your repository in GitHub...

Imagine the scenario in which main or master is your primary branch, and also you have another branch as dev, and your dev branch is N commits behind main or master, and there's nothing about this living in your local machine.

How to proceed...

Firstly you have to make a clone from the Github repository to your machine, however, at first, your local git doesn't have to know about your secondary branch status, only from the main or master, so Git gets only your remote label branch updated, and there are no commits yet in your local.

So, what you need is at least 1 commit, 1 push to main or master, and 1 pull back to you local.

Do NOT push anything for your dev branch else you would have 1 commit ahead and N commits behind main or master (so, conflicts)...

So, you'll need an auxiliary branch to send a Pull Request to your remote main or master.

Without further ado. How to proceed in this scenario:

Ater cloning the repository...

`git checkout -b aux-branch`  -> it'll create and checkout the branch

Now, you have to make at least one change in order to record a first commit in you local Git, suposing you haven't anything to implement at the moment... Take the README.md file to change a letter, a space, a blank line more...

`git status`          -> you'll see your README file was modified
`git add README.md`   -> to add it to staged area, ready to the commit
`git commit -m "modified readme file"`
`git push -u origin aux-branch` -> it should generate a link that'll lead you to your repository to open and accept the ordered Pull Request.

I use accepting that with Rebase and Merge (the last option in green button when dropdown), after the accepting GitHub will ask you if you want to delete aux-branch... yes you want, so delete, 'cause your main or master now has this newest feature brought by aux-branch.
Now back to your local (Git), proceed this following way:

`git checkout main` or master
`git branch -D aux-branch` -> to Delete in your local too\
`git remote update --prune`-> it makes both fetch and update to your remote.
`git pull`                 -> to receive the newest updates from remote GHub.
`git checkout dev`
`git rebase dev main` or master -> (rebase or merge)
`git push -u origin dev`        -> climbing the updates to your remote branch

Now go to your GitHub reload the page, drop down to your dev branch you'll see your dev branch is the same as your main/master branch...

So that's it. I hope I helped you guys...

Answer (score 0):

If the message says that you are 'n' commits **behind** master, then you can use the 'git sync' option in tortoise git. Where you will be prompted to select from the branch (target) that you want to pull your changes from. Hit 'Pull'. This will pull all the changes from remote (master/any target branch) into your development branch. After pulling, hit 'Push' to push all the synced changes from your local development branch to remote development branch on git.

Answer (score 0):

In intelliJ you can do following simple steps -
checkout your branch and pull latest commits from main/branch name
Merge those changes in your branch . - > vcs -> git -> merge changes (origin/main)

push your branch to remote

This should make your branch same as target

Comment: Anagha, kindly improve your answer by adding proper commands

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the behind branch is local and you want to update it with the remote master branch
you can do it easily using GitHub Desktop:

1. Choose the local branch as the current branch
2. Go to `branch` menu and click on `Update from master`
3. Go to `Repository` menu and click  `Push`

Answer (score -4):

If the branch is behind master, then delete the remote branch. Then go to local branch and run :

```
git pull origin master --rebase
```

Then, again push the branch to origin:

```
git push -u origin <branch-name>
```

Comment: please think about keeping the commit history. deleting any commit wonts works. not a good approach.