# This branch is 123 commits behind tardis-sn:master

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and don't know much about it can anyone help me with this how to get this right it is saying 123 commits behind.
I have all tried this what no luck. [What I can do to resolve "1 commit behind master"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118404/what-i-can-do-to-resolve-1-commit-behind-master)

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you're that far behind it's time for `git pull`.

Comment: Could you write what have you tried?

Comment: @MicheleDorigatti I don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: @tadman git pull is giving me error.

Comment: What is your goal, why do you want your branch to be in sync with master? It is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: Everything is working fine.Before i see this.
I am all the latest file from the master locally. And can make a pull request for the same. But i am not able to update my repositery (i.e forked one) because i don't know how to update it. I was following this post https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/create-directory/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short-Answer:

If you want to update your local branch from the remote branch, do `git pull --rebase`

This will pull all the remote changes and commit them into your local branch, then it will put your local change on top of it. You can then move on with adding local commits and merging to the remote (if you want).